# How to Add Image(jpg, png..) the Winforms MSChart FlotArea in C#?

Tags: winforms, mschart

I used Winforms Chart control [BackImage] property to insert an image as follows (CIE1931 image).

[Back Image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5NAdu.jpg)

I'm trying to Add the Image in FlotArea.
I couldn't find the property window.

I've been looking all day since yesterday, but I couldn't solve it.

Is this possible? I'd like to hear your opinions..

Comment: Hello and welcome to StackOverflow. Please take some time to read the help page, especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Further, please read the [Stack Overflow question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist). Also learn how to post [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: @jay Gray Thank you for your advice. I'll be more careful with the questions.